# How to use Application Module methods from POJO

Tags: oracle-adf

in model project, i have regular BC AM. Next to it i have POJO classes and created POJO data control. This pojo data Control should call methods from AM to retrieve data - basically act as proxy to BC AM.

How to correctly call Application Module and its methods from POJO? I found examples with EJB and servlets just.

Answer (score 0):

THis may help. In JDeveloper, create a new Java class. Inside the class type

```
bc4j
```

then press Ctl+Enter
This will replace the code with  template code that shows how to access an AM from "plain Java."
This can be a good place to start.

Joe

Comment: Somehow doesn't work. I want to do get AM in pojo at model project, is it fundamentally ok?

Comment: do you mean get access to the AM from a POJO that you added to your Model Project?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are trying to do.  How do you get access to your POJO in the model project? from where?

Comment: Yes, I was trying to call AM from POJO, which is in the same ModelProject as AM. But i found how to feed Gantt component with POJO in ADFfacesDemo application, so this question is irrelevant for me now.